# Not getting data from nodemcu to the firebase

Tags: esp8266, arduino

I've done almost everything to get the data from nodemcu but nothing happened.

1. I tried by changing the fingerprint.
2. I have also used project secret and copy it in FIREBASE_AUTH part.
3. I also tried by making rules true.

I'm using the firebase demo code.

What is going wrong?

Comment: have you checked the basics, like network connectivity?

Comment: I found myself the answer.There was issue with the fingerprint.Every individual databsae has different fingerprint code.I have found myself from a site by inputting my database domain name.